# Run [Run] section before [Files] section

Tags: inno-setup

My setup downloads a file called `launcher.zip` to the `{tmp}` folder and during and after installation it runs the following scripts:

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "{tmp}\launchers\Launcher"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist recursesubdirs external;

[Run]
Filename: "{tmp}\7zip\7za.exe"; Parameters: "x ""{tmp}\launchers\launcher.zip"" -o""{tmp}\launchers"" * -r -aoa"; Flags: runhidden runascurrentuser;
```

But this way the `[Files]` section runs before the `[Run]` section so it doesn't find the folder extracted to the `{tmp}` folder.

I could just make the `[Run]` script extract to the destination folder, but I want to use the `[Files]` section to set the `Flags: onlyifdoesntexist`

Because I don't want it to replace files when extracting, unless a specific `Component` is selected, which in this case is `launchers\reinstall` *(Another script removes the files if `Component` is selected)*

So I need the `[Run]` section script to be executed before the `[Files]` section

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of running a `[Run]` section, I ran a `[Codes]` section to extract, and added a `BeforeInstall` to my `[Files]` section

My answer here:
[Extract file during installation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71055252/15825492)