# Extract file during installation

Tags: inno-setup

I'm trying to extract a file using 7zip in the `[Codes]` section as I want to extract before any files get copied by the `[Files]` section.

With the code below I am not getting it, I tried and changed it, but it appears that `The system cannot find the specified file`

Am I doing something wrong?

```pascal
[Files]

// Copy 7za.exe to {tmp} folder
Source: "tools\7zip\7za.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}\7zip"; Flags: deleteafterinstall;

Source: "{tmp}\launchers\Launcher1"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist external; BeforeInstall: ExtractLauncher
Source: "{tmp}\launchers\Launcher2"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist external; BeforeInstall: ExtractLauncher

// --------------------------- Extract Launcher --------------------------- \\

[Code]
var
 ResultCode: integer;

procedure ExtractLauncher();
begin                                                                               
  Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\7zip\7za.exe'), 'x "{tmp}\launchers\launcher.zip" -o"{tmp}\launchers" * -r -aoa', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) 
  MsgBox(SysErrorMessage(ResultCode), mbError, MB_OK);
end;
```

The `launcher.zip` file is downloaded during installation to the `{tmp}\launchers` folder

I kept looking at the `{tmp}` folder, and the `launcher.zip` file and `7za.exe` are created before running my `[Codes]`, I did this to make sure they were there when run the code.
And yes, they were there before running the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Martin's Prikryl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/850848/martin-prikryl) comment, I just added `ExpandConstant` to the rest of the command line and the code worked!

It was like this:

```pascal
[Files]

// Copy 7za.exe to {tmp} folder
Source: "tools\7zip\7za.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}\7zip"; Flags: deleteafterinstall;

Source: "{tmp}\launchers\Launcher1"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist external; BeforeInstall: ExtractLauncher
Source: "{tmp}\launchers\Launcher2"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist external; BeforeInstall: ExtractLauncher

// --------------------------- Extract Launcher ---------------------------

[Code]
var
 ResultCode: integer;

procedure ExtractLauncher();
begin                                                                               
  Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\7zip\7za.exe'), ' x ' + ExpandConstant('{tmp}\launchers\launcher.zip') + ' -o' + ExpandConstant('{tmp}\launchers') + ' * -r -aoa', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) 
  MsgBox(SysErrorMessage(ResultCode), mbError, MB_OK);
end;
```

Comment: Glad it helped. Though next time you get solution, allow the one who suggested it, to post his/hers answer, instead of re-posting it yourself.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll remove it for you to post it! :)

Comment: @MartinPrikryl in fairness to the OP, you did have the opportunity to post an answer instead of just leaving a comment.  (Not that your point is invalid in general, and its a a good thing to mention to a newer user.)